# VAL function in SQLCE 4.0

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Im switching from mdb to SQLCE 4.0 for many reasons and the most import thing is the security,

Everything is going good so far until trying to switching VAL function that in mdb to SQLCE

```
mdb VAL function/     GG: [degree]![A1]+[degree]![A2]+Val([degree]![M1])+Val([degree]![M2])+Val([degree]![D1])
```

The idea from this function is to see the "first and second left" part of the the field, if it continuous characters i want this function to return -1 if numbers is ok to view any numbers

The hole conversation process that im doing is depend on this function if i could not find solution i may return to mdb :(

Comment: Run the Val function in code

Comment: Hi Erik , but if i run the val function from code that will do like loop on every record "more than 12,000 record" and i believe that will slow down the application , is there any way to run the val function in query against SQLCE or is there any equivalent of this function ?

Comment: Avoid getting all 12000 records at once by using paging (OFFSET / FECTH)